# What is the Laplace transform of a Linear Time-Varying system?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fourier-transform, degrees-of-freedom, complex-systems, laplace-transform

**The Problem**

I have the following damped mass-spring system in the form of a Linear Time-Varying (LTV) system:

$$\mathbf{M}(t)\mathbf{\ddot{x}}(t) + \mathbf{C\dot{x}}(t) + \mathbf{Kx}(t) = \mathbf{f}(t) \tag{1}$$

where $\mathbf{M}(t)$ is a diagonal time-dependent mass matrix with sinusoidal functions on its diagonal (can be easily decomposed using Fourier series), $\mathbf{C}$ and $\mathbf{K}$ are tridiagonal matrices and $\mathbf{f}(t)$ is the forcing vector.

I would like to find the Laplace transform of Eq.(1), however due to the time dependent term on the left hand side, I am unsure to do this.

---

**My Attempt**

What I would normaly do if $\mathbf{M}$ was not time dependent, is that I would easily take the Laplace function to find the transfer function:

\begin{gather}
  [\mathbf{M}s^2 + \mathbf{C}s + \mathbf{K}]\mathbf{x}(s) = \mathbf{f}(s) \\
  \Rightarrow [-\mathbf{M}\omega^2 + \mathbf{C}j\omega + \mathbf{K}]\mathbf{x}(j\omega) = \mathbf{f}(j\omega)
\end{gather}

What I have done in this case is I have simply taken the average of $\mathbf{M}$ and performed the same as above, however as advised by the literature on the specific physical problem that I am tackling this approximation results to innacurate results.

Therefore, how would I be able to find the Laplace transform of Eq.(1), or at least a method to approximate it better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while there is no general formula for Laplace transform of a product of two functions, if the functions in ${\bf M}$ are only comprised of sine and cosine, you can use the fact that
$$ L[\sin(\omega t) f(t)](s) = -i\frac{L[f](s-i\omega) - L[f](s+i\omega)}{2}$$
and for cosine
$$ L[\cos(\omega t) f(t)](s) = \frac{L[f](s-i\omega) + L[f](s+i\omega)}{2}$$

Comment: Actually this is very useful since with a simple Fourier decomposition of the elements of the mass matrix I might be able to get a good approximation of the time varying term in the frequency domain.

Comment: If the functions are square integrable, you can define the Laplace transform of the product of two functions using a known formula. See the Multiplication entry on this page  Section Properties and Theorems https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform# . This being said, the formula is not very easy to use. There is also an extension of the Plancherel Theorem for Fourier to Laplace transforms under some assumptions, the Laplace can be seen as the FT of $f(t)e^{-tx}$ with $s=x+iy$.